# Why I am getting the error regarding maven libraries?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, maven, intellij-idea

Java:cannot access com.azure.core.util.BinaryData
class file for com.azure.core.util.BinaryData not found.

While running the main application I am getting this error, how to resolve this, I tried maven installation in local & checked the libraries, still some of the libraries are missing

Comment: Could you add more details like your pom file?

Answer (score 1):

This means that either you're missing the neccessary dependency or the repository for that class is missing. If you are missing the dependency add this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

It shouldn't be a problem to find it since it is in the central repo